# LaTeX and Textmate

Tags: errors, installing, distributions, textmate

I have been trying to get to grips with TextMate for creating LaTeX files and when I go to view the file I get an error: can't find kpsewhich on path.

I have two questions: Do I have to have a LaTeX programme (MacTeX)?

Shall I add kpsewhich to the path?
I am confused..

Comment: Yes, you need a LaTeX distribution, such as MacTeX. This contains all the packages and program files needed to compile your LaTeX document, an editor alone isn't enough.

Comment: As @TorbjørnT. said, just install MacTeX. We will close the question for know. If you installed MacTeX but the problem persists, tell us, we could re-open the question then.